# Batch - Printing Echo is OFF

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo

I have the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf) DO (
  ECHO %%A
  IF "%%A" EQU "DZE_BuildOnRoads = false; // Default: False" (
    TYPE D:\god-bases\god-bases.txt
  )
) >> temp.txt
move /y temp.txt %ThisService_WorkingDirectory%MPMissions\%ThisService_mapname%\init.sqf
```

How do I stop this from printing "Echo is OFF" in blank space?

Comment: Have you tried putting @ before ECHO %%A?

Comment: According to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772462.aspx) what you have there should already work. Can you provide a more minimal example?

Comment: Take a look at this thread on DosTips.com: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554)

Answer (score 3):

Change `echo %%A` to `echo(%%A`.

This will avoid problems with nearly all possible combinations of %%A like
`<empty>`, `ON` or `/?`